# Is there a <scroll-container> or <scroll-page> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, tags

Recently I came across a code block on MDN which contains two unfamiliar tags namely scroll-container and scroll-page.

After some research, I couldn't find any info regarding these tags.

Please what are their roles and does someone have any info concerning them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
          <a href="#page-1">1</a>
          <a href="#page-2">2</a>
          <a href="#page-3">3</a>
        </nav>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


        <scroll-container>
          <scroll-page id="page-1">1</scroll-page>
          <scroll-page id="page-2">2</scroll-page>
          <scroll-page id="page-3">3</scroll-page>
        </scroll-container>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the custom tag available in HTML5. Custom elements are new types of DOM elements that can be defined by authors. Unlike decorators, which are stateless and ephemeral, custom elements can encapsulate state and provide script interfaces.
[Sources](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)